QField - Pictures cannot be transferred to PC
QField updated automatically on my tablet this week.
Now I can see pictures I took inside of the Qfield app, which I couldn't do beforehand.
However, since that very same update, I'm unable to move my pictures from my tablet to my computer.
I used to be able to, as all of the pictures I took ended up in the 'DCIM' folder of my project folder, on my tablet.
But now, the 'DCIM' folder is empty.
I know for a fact I haven't deleted the pictures, as I can still open them inside of QField.
Has anyone had the same issue ?
